# How to update the global font color for all Plotly charts?

Tags: python, plotly

I have a notebook with around ~20 different plots.
Currently, I'm manually changing the color with this command in each plot function:

```
fig.update_layout(font = dict(color = '#051c2c')) 
return fig
```

This seems a bit redundant, is there a way to define a global color or font option for all of Plotly?

Comment: I did some research, but it seems that it is not possible to set the default font. Functional restrictions can be set in `config=dict(font=dict(color='#dc143c'))` and `fig.show(config=config)`, but fonts were not enabled.

Comment: @AxW Thank you for accepting my answer. If you found my suggestion useful, upvotes are always welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to use Plotly Dash or [JupyterDash](https://medium.com/plotly/introducing-jupyterdash-811f1f57c02e), this could be done through [stylesheets](https://dash.plotly.com/layout). To my knowledge, your only option seems to be to edit your figure objects directly through [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals). Just make sure that all your figures follow some sort of system when it comes to naming, like `fig1`, `fig2` etc:

```
for l in list(locals().keys()):
    if l[:3] == 'fig':
        locals()[l].update_layout(font_family = 'Old Standard TT', font_size = 24)
```

Here are four figures to show that this little snippet will in fact edit the fonts for a collection of figures `fig1` and `fig2` following the locic above.

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# data
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {0: 1000, 1: 996, 2: 996},
                   'b': {0: 1000, 1: 1007, 2: 998},
                   'c': {0: 1000, 1: 1009, 2: 999}})

# figure setup and display
fig1 = px.scatter(df, x = 'a', y='c', title = 'Figure 1')
fig2  = px.bar(df, x = 'a', y='c', title = 'Figure 2')
fig2.update_layout(font=dict(family = 'Courier New'))
fig1.show()
fig2.show()

# some brute force editing
keys = list(locals().keys())
for l in keys:
    if l[:3] == 'fig':
        locals()[l].update_layout(font_color = 'firebrick', font_size = 16)

# display after editing
fig1.show()
fig2.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create your own theme. This can be combined with other themes, meaning you can override the bits of the config you care about and let Plotly handle the rest. The chained themes are handled like CSS, so later themes override earlier themes.

```
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Register your theme as a named template
pio.templates['my_theme'] = go.layout.Template(
    layout=dict(
        font=dict(
            color='#051c2c',
        ),
    ),
)

# Combine your theme with plotly's default
pio.templates.default = 'plotly+my_theme'
```

For more information, check out Plotly's docs on the matter
https://plotly.com/python/templates/#creating-themes